# How can i get my discord bot to send a message after i press a reaction in python?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

So, I'm making a rock paper scissors bot. So far it'll send a message with 3 reactions, :mountain: :page_facing_up: and :scissors:. If I react with :mountain: it would reply with a message 'Paper' Basically impossible difficulty rock paper scissors game

My code so far:

```
client = discord.Client()

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('login successful {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot \
        and message.content.startswith('!rps'):
        msg2 = await message.channel.send('**Rock Paper Scissors**\n:mountain: Rock\n:page_facing_up: Paper\n:scissors: Scissors')
        await msg2.add_reaction('⛰')
        await msg2.add_reaction('')
        await msg2.add_reaction('✂')

client.run(' --- ')
```

Comment: Are you using a bot? Or are you using a client? Don't use both

Comment: You should really be using [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) instead of on_message for commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) a reaction to be added. You will have to specify a check command to make sure only certain reactions are responded to.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot \
        and message.content.startswith('!rps'):
        msg2 = await message.channel.send('**Rock Paper Scissors**\n:mountain: Rock\n:page_facing_up: Paper\n:scissors: Scissors')
        await msg2.add_reaction('⛰')
        await msg2.add_reaction('')
        await msg2.add_reaction('✂')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return str(reaction) in ('', '⛰', '✂') and user == message.author and reaction.message == msg2 # Only three reactions and the command caller is allowed to use this

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=30.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError: # If user takes too long to react
            return await message.channel.send("You took too long to react")

        if str(reaction) == '':
            await message.channel.send('✂... I win!!')
        elif str(reaction) == '✂':
            await message.channel.send('⛰... I win!!')
        elif str(reaction) == '⛰':
            await message.channel.send('... I win!!')
```

In essence, this command will wait for a reaction from the user on the message. It will then check which emoji was reacted and send the appropriate emoji to win rps!